# config undefined in environment specific configuration files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I start my server locally, I get the following notice:

```
please set config.active_support.deprecation to :log at config/environments/development.rb
```

When I add  in config/environments/development.rb

```
config.active_support.deprecation = :log
```

I get:

```
undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)
```

my environment:
Rails 3.0.1 Ruby 1.8.7 Ubuntu 10.04

Development.rb file

```
# Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/environment.rb

# In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
# every request.  This slows down response time but is perfect for development
# since you don't have to restart the webserver when you make code changes.
config.active_support.deprecation = :log
config.cache_classes = false
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your development.rb it should have a block that looks like:

```
YourApplicationName::Application.configure do
   config.active_support.deprecation = :log
   config.cache_classes = false
end
```

The config lines must be placed inside that block.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add the line where the other config.* options are - inside the *.configure loop.

Comment: I'm confused.  Anything confing.* gives the same error in the config/environments/development.rb file

Comment: Can you post some/all of your development.rb file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 rails s -e development
```