# Error using Rails and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

error using Rails 3.1 and Heroku, below is the error I get when I try `heroku rake db:migrate`, any help on this is highly appreciated.

```
Arugil1 git:(master) heroku rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environmen

(See full trace by running task with --trace)



    ➜  Arugil1 git:(master) heroku rake db:migrate --trace
    ** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
    ** Invoke environment (first_time)
    ** Execute environment
    rake aborted!
    undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object
    /app/config/environment.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-        3.1.0.rc6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in `require'
    /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in `block in require'
    /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
    /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:636:in `new_constants_in'
    /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
   /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in `require'
    /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc6/lib/rails/application.rb:78:in `require_environment!'
    /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc6/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
    /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
    /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
    /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
    /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
    /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
    /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
    /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
    /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
    /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block in top_level'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `block in run'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

Also below is the Gemfile content:

```
➜  Arugil1 git:(master) ✗   more Gemfile | grep racer
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'therubyracer-heroku', '0.8.1.pre3'
gem 'therubyracer-heroku', '0.8.1.pre3'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'therubyracer-heroku', '0.8.1.pre3'
gem 'therubyracer'
```

And the environmnet.rb output:

```
➜  Arugil1 git:(master) ✗ more config/environment.rb 
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)
# Initialize the rails application
DMr::Application.initialize!`
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but perhaps this thread might be of help

[config undefined in environment specific configuration files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044441/config-undefined-in-environment-specific-configuration-files)