# Unable to open rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am unable to open my rails console.I am getting the following error.

```
[ramya@sanduxvm01 tcm]$ rails console
/home/ramya/tcm/tcm/config/environment.rb:7: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:22
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6
```

Comment: Please post the contents of `config/environment.rb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's probably a mis-configuration in your config/environment.rb file!**

Double check that the syntax of that file is correct

Also:

[config undefined in environment specific configuration files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044441/config-undefined-in-environment-specific-configuration-files)

Comment: it would be easier if we could see the env.rb file itself, but usually this errors are caused by a "config.xxxx" line outside the initializer block that sets up the config block var.

Comment: Thanks a lot.That solved the problem.Some error in the environments.rb file